# GCC warning on implicit casting of void* to another pointer type

Tags: c, gcc, casting, warnings, void-pointers

As the title says, is there a way to force GCC to warn me when I do something like this:

```
void do_something(int* ptr)
{
    // do something
}

int main()
{
    int a = 123;
    void* b = &a;

    // WARN HERE:
    do_something(b);
}
```

Comment: And there is no warning about `void* b = &a;` where the type information is lost?

Comment: I compiled that snippet just then with my usual warning flags (`-pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith  -Wcast-qual -Wextra`) and there wasn't any warning. That's not the part I'm particularly worried about however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-Wc++-compat`. From the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -Wc++-compat (C and Objective-C only)
>
> Warn about ISO C constructs that
>   are outside of the common subset of ISO C and ISO C++, e.g. request
>   for implicit conversion from void * to a pointer to non-void type.

Comment: Does just what I need, fantastic!

Comment: It only issues warnings, it doesn't change GCC's behaviour. The compiled output will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons why the answer is probably **no**:

1. This is legal C.
2. It would be pretty annoying in other contexts, e.g.

   `int *array = malloc(5 * sizeof(*array))`.

Comment: I appreciate your concerns but this doesn't really help me with my question